# Retrieve custom fields from customer table using SQL

Tags: magento2, sql, table, custom-field

I have two custom fields in my customer table, namely *nickname* and *sponsor*. I would like to create an sql query to select the two custom fields that I have in the table. What kind of query should I do?

Comment: in magento1 or magento2  and what is table name ?

Comment: Itś Magento 2 and the name of the table is 'mgfx_customer_entity'

Comment: Why you dont need to use repository or collection its eav entity its not simple to get with sql query and its not recomended

Comment: Só, how can I do it? I’m a newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use in your phtml file where you need .

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
         $customers = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection')->load();
         foreach($customers as $customer){
           echo $customer->getNickname();
           echo $customer->Sponsor();
         }
```

or you can get these value by block using module like as

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
class Customer extends Template
{    
   protected $customerFactory;
   public function __construct(       
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory  $customerFactory,
    )
    {    
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;

    }

    public function getCustomerCollection(){

        $collection=$this->customerFactory->create()->getCollection();
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

And add below code in phtml file inside that module

```
$customers=$block->getCustomerCollection();
    foreach($customers as $customer){
    echo $customer->getNickname();
    echo $customer->Sponsor();
    }
```